# Can packfiles contain OBJ_REF_DELTA pointing to objects in the same pack?

Tags: git, git-bundle

The official [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/pack-format) describes the format of packfiles to include 6 types of objects, i.e. `Commit`, `Blob`, `Tree`, `Tag`, `OffsetDelta` and `RefDelta`. `OffsetDelta` is clearly described as being defined in context of an object (which itself can be a delta) earlier in the pack. However, `RefDelta` can be defined in context of any object based solely on the `ObjectId`.

The documentation mentions that `RefDelta`s are typically used to delta against objects outside the pack (so called `thin-packs`) but can they be used to delta against objects in the same pack? I am manually generating packfiles so I am curious to know the standard practice with respect to packfile format.